# How to fix: The first time OnCreate() is called, I can't retrieve data from Retrofit Concrete Class

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm retrieving data from a REST API using Retrofit. First I tried everything on the MainActivity and it worked great.
Then, I moved some methods to a singleton pattern ClientApi class (is this the right approach? I think it is but I didn't do it properly)
Now, I can't see the results on the first OnCreate() method, all I see is "null".
Finally, if I wait 1 second and rotate the phone to change to landscape (so onCreate() is called again) it works.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UI components
    TextView textViewHello;
    //variables
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewHello = findViewById(R.id.text_hello);
        ClientApi clientApi = ClientApi.getInstance();
        Client client = clientApi.getClient(2);
        String clientString = client.toString();
        textViewHello.setText(clientString);
    }
}
```

```java
public class ClientApi {

    private static final String TAG = "ClientApi";
    private static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/";
    private ClientsService clientsService;
    public Client client = new Client();

    private static ClientApi instance = null;

    private ClientApi() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        clientsService = retrofit.create(ClientsService.class);
    }

    public static ClientApi getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ClientApi();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Client getClient(int clientId){
        getClient1(clientId);
        return client;
    }

    private void getClient1(int clientId) {
        Call<Client> call = clientsService.getClient(clientId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Client>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Client> call, Response<Client> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    client = response.body();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response successfull, client: " + client);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response not successfull: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Client> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The expected result is to see the information about one client on the first time the app is started. But I can't see it until I change to landscape or portrait.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

When clientApi.getClient(2) is called the immediate value returned is
a fresh instance of client created in your class ClientApi, so when OnCreate is called again the data is available because your api is finished

```
public Client client = new Client();
```

If method **private void getClient1(int clientId) {...}** is asynchronous you need to pass a listener to receive the result of your API has already returned the data

Something like that

```
// create a interface to your response
public interface ApiResponse {
   onResponse(Object response);
}
```

```
//update your getClient method
public void getClient(int clientId, ApiResponse apiResponse){
    getClient1(clientId, apiResponse);
    return client;
}
```

```
//update your getClient1 method and call the listener
private void getClient1(int clientId, ApiResponse apiResponse) {
        Call<Client> call = clientsService.getClient(clientId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Client>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Client> call, Response<Client> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    client = response.body();
                    // Call the listener
                    // apiResponse.onResponse(client)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response successfull, client: " + client);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response not successfull: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Client> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Then in your MainActivity call your api method

```
Client client = clientApi.getClient(2, new ApiResponse() {
    @Override()
    public void onResponse(Object response) {
       // response is your client data
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't realize that the Retrofit is working asynchronous when using `call.enqueue()`. When the first time you're calling the following:

```
    ClientApi clientApi = ClientApi.getInstance();
    Client client = clientApi.getClient(2);
    String clientString = client.toString();
    textViewHello.setText(clientString);
```

`client` variable in `ClientApi` isn't filled yet with the data from Retrofit call. But when you waiting 1 second then rotate the device, your `client` variable is already filled with data from the previous Retrofit call. So, you actually didn't get the current data in your TextView.

You need to either using a callback or pass your TextView to your `ClientApi` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching your client asynchronousely but you are processing the result as if it were a synchronous call. `client` will hold the value you want after `onResponse` is called. I can suggest you create a private listener that will notify you when the value of `client` changes.

For that, I could proceed this way:

```java
public interface OnClientFetchedListener{
  void onClientFetched(Client client);
  void onError(String errorMessage);
}
```

Then create a member in `ClientApi` of type `OnClientFetchedListener` and add a setter. Then call invoke an appropriate method when on success or on error. That can be achieved this way:

```java
public class ClientApi {

    private static final String TAG = "ClientApi";
    private static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/";
    private ClientsService clientsService;
    public Client client = new Client();

    private static ClientApi instance = null;

    //our listener is just here
    private OnClientFetchedListener listener;

    //our setter is just here
    public void setListener(OnClientFetchedListener listener){
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    private ClientApi() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        clientsService = retrofit.create(ClientsService.class);
    }

    public static ClientApi getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ClientApi();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Client getClient(int clientId){
        getClient1(clientId);
        return client;
    }

    private void getClient1(int clientId) {
        Call<Client> call = clientsService.getClient(clientId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Client>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Client> call, Response<Client> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    client = response.body();

                  //invoke an appropriate method when on success
                  if(listener!=null)
                  {listener.onClientFetched(client);
                  }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response successfull, client: " + client);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response not successfull: " + response.code());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Client> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                //invoke an appropriate method when on failure
                  if(listener!=null)
                  {listener.onError(t.getMessage());
                  }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then after, inside the `onCreate` set a listener to the `ClientApi` object and listen to events. You can make your activity/fragment implement the interface if you want. The first way can be achieved this way:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //UI components
    TextView textViewHello;
    //variables
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewHello = findViewById(R.id.text_hello);
        ClientApi clientApi = ClientApi.getInstance();

        //let's set our listener
        clientApi.setListener(new OnClientFetchedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClientFetched(Client client)
        {
          if(client!=null)
          {
            String clientString = client.toString();
        textViewHello.setText(clientString);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String errorMessage)
        {
        //log the error or something else
        }
        });


    }
}
```

Any way, this is how I could this about that. There are too many solutions...